# SQLite Encryption in BlackBerry

Tags: sqlite, blackberry, mobile, encryption

How can I provide seamless encryption for the SQLite database used by my app. I'm looking for something similar to [SQLCypher](http://sqlcipher.net/documentation) which transparently handles the encryption behind the scenes so that the app does not have to worry about it. There's no release for SQLCypher for BlackBerry mentioned on their site even though there are releases for Android and iOS. Is it possible to use SQLCypher or is there an alternative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RIM provides a cryptographic interface for working with SQLite.  It is quite easy to work with.  See [DatabaseSecurityOptions](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.1.0api/net/rim/device/api/database/DatabaseSecurityOptions.html) and [DatabaseFactory](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.1.0api/net/rim/device/api/database/DatabaseFactory.html).create() or [DatabaseFactory](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/7.1.0api/net/rim/device/api/database/DatabaseFactory.html).open() with the appropriate arguments.  By using a CodeSigningKey, the database will be readable only by apps signed with the same key, on that same device.  If the database is moved to a different device, the data will be unreadable.  If the database is accessed by a different app, it will be unreadable.